# read .accdb file through php

Tags: php, odbc

I am trying to upload  .accdb file and then try to read it but I am getting error

```
Warning (2): odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect

$db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName;", '', '');
```

But when upload .mdb file and using following odbc_connection it's working fine.

```
 $db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName;", '', '');
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your server may not have the latest Access Database Engine installed.

[Microsoft Download Centre](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)